# Close the Auxiliary route from anywhere in the Angular 2 application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How to get the Route info without the aux route? The scenario is to close out the aux route, to do that I am thinking of stripping down the aux route info from the current route and navigate to new route,

So what I am looking for is to strip down `aux1-route` from the current route.

```
/route1(aux1:aux1-route;id=123)  -> /route1
/route1(aux1:aux1-route;id=123//aux2:aux2-route) -> /route1(aux2:aux2-route)
```

**app.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name='aux1'></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name='aux2'></router-outlet>
```

**route configuration**

```
{ path: "route1", component: route1Component }
{ path: "aux1-route", component: aux1RouteComponent, outlet: "aux1" }
{ path: "aux2-route", component: aux2RouteComponent, outlet: "aux2" }
```

`Angular 2 version : 2.0.0-rc.5`

`Angular Router version : 3.0.0-rc.1`

Please also suggest if there is any alternate way to close the aux route from anywhere in the application.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using below code,

```
  this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { aux1: null } }]);
```

Check this [Angular documentation](http://[routerLink]=%22[%7B%20outlets:%20%7B%20popup:%20['new']%20%7D%20%7D]%22)

Comment: Awesome! Spent 4 hours on this.

Comment: @Weblurk: Glad it helped.

Comment: Sadly, there is a bug in the Angular router which means this doesn't currently work. Ref: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15338